# convert RTRIM (PL/SQL to T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

I need to convert this PL-SQL to T-SQL.

```
rtrim([FIELDA],';')    --this from PL-SQL
```

What is the equivalent of `rtrim`? Since `rtrim` in t-sql only removes the spaces and not characters.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
;with TEST(FIELDA) as (
    select ';' union
    select ';;' union
    select 'a;' union
    select ';b;' union
    select ';cc;' union
    select ';ddd;;' union
    select ';eeee;;;' union
    select 'fffff' union
    select ';ggggg' 
)

select 
    FIELDA, 
    left(FIELDA, 1 + len(FIELDA) - patindex('%[^;]%', reverse('Z' + FIELDA)))
from TEST


FIELDA      (No column name)
;   
;;  
;b;         ;b
;cc;        ;cc
;ddd;;      ;ddd
;eeee;;;    ;eeee
;ggggg      ;ggggg
a;          a
fffff       fffff
```

Comment: This works with mid-string ; characters as well (like 'hh;;hh;;').  Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT-

This will trim off the last character from the right, works the same with `LEFT`

```
RIGHT([Field], LEN([Field])-1)
```

Although this assumes you know how much needs to be removed at the end of the string.

Comment: you cna do this in PL-SQL SHOW RTRIM('Last Wordxxyxy','xy') and result is "Last Word" [link]http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2076.htm
How do i do this in T-sql??

Comment: i dont know what this rtrim([FIELDA],';') is doing on the oracle side but i need a function(s) to do the exact the same thing on T-sql. but i dont think it is only removing the last character..

Comment: @telexx- if you follow the link from my first comment. you can see it is doing more than just removing the last character.